# Replace one arrays keys with another arrays values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to map form fields to database fields.

I have two arrays..

One array is the **data** and contains the form field id as the key and the form field value as the value.

```
$data = array("inputEmail"=>"someone@somewhere.com","inputName"=>"someone"... etc
```

I also have an array which i intended to use as a **map.** The keys of this array are the same as the form fields and the values are the database field names.

```
$map = array("inputEmail"=>"email", "inputName"=>"name"... etc
```

What i want to do is iterate over the data array and where the data key matches the map key assign a new key to the data array which is the value of the map array.

```
$newArray = array("email"=>"someone@somewhere.com", "name"=>"someone"...etc
```

My question is how? Ive tried so many different ways im now totally lost in it.

Comment: Why not simply having the same names across the application? ;)

Comment: The input field names are important for the form validation to work. But i know what you mean. I thought this would be simpler than changing the whole applications input field names and also the validation script.

Comment: If I could give an advice: Try to use the same names across application if **any** possible. You'll be saved from many, many headaches. Also it is good for automatic code generation and so on...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is made quite nice with a foreach loop

```
foreach( $data as $origKey => $value ){
  // New key that we will insert into $newArray with
  $newKey = $map[$origKey];
  $newArray[$newKey] = $value;
}
```

A more condensed approach (eliminating variable used for clarification)

```
foreach( $data as $origKey => $value ){
  $newArray[$map[$origKey]] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to replace keys of one array with values of the other the solution is [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

print_r output

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: `array_combine` does not do what the user is after in this instance.

Comment: @SamLanning as per the title `Replace one arrays keys with another arrays values in php` the above answer is correct so better not to negative rate it. As it can help people who want to replace keys of one array with values of the other.

Comment: array_combine() expects both arrays to be of equal length. One cannot assume that is the case here.

Comment: This is awsome solutions. Easiest. Should have been acepted. Thank you